# что быстрее извлечение среза или pop

Tags: python, списки

Есть большой список l, какая операция быстрее

```
a=l.pop()
```

или

```
a=l[-1]
l=l[:-1]
```

Comment: А почему бы не замерить?

Comment: Возьми, да измерь, в чем сложность то?

Comment: pop из начала list и из конца, очень разно по времени будет

Answer (score 1):

Согласно python wiki [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) срез по k-тый елемент осуществляется за О(k) в среднем случае.

```
l = ['a', 1, b'byte']
id(l)
58706920
id(l[:-1])
58368248
```

в результате среза создается новый объект с требуемым диапазоном.

О том как устроен list изнутри предлагаю почитать тут [Python list implementation](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/)

кратко, операция pop():

- возвращает элемент, на который ссылается последний элемент в массиве
- обновляется индекс последнего элемента (size -= 1)
- и если current_size < allocated_size / 2 то происходит shrink (сужение) выделенной памяти

это даёт нам возможность принимать сложность pop() операции за О(1) "в среднем".

pop() не создает новый объект:

```
l = ['a', 1, b'byte']
id(l)
58908424
l.pop()
b'byte'
id(l)
58908424
```

**ОТВЕТ** pop() операция быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Например: Измерить можно вот так:

```
import time
class Profiler(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._startTime = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("Elapsed time: {:.20f} sec".format(time.time() - self._startTime))

with Profiler() as pop:
    a=l.pop()

with Profiler() as pop2:
    a=l[-1]
    l=l[:-1]
```